# How to make Weather Particle System convincing when Parented to player?

Tags: unity, particles, graphic-effects

I have a Particle System of a blizzard effect and I'm trying to make it look convincing that the player is really walking through a blizzard as they traverse the map.

Because it is a small particle system, I opted to make the Player Camera its parent so it follows Player around. But when the Player Camera moves, the Blizzard doesn't convincingly move with it.

Gif of problem:

[image: Effect trails further away as camera moves]

Particle System settings:

[image: Particle System settings]

How can I make the effect look more believable?

Comment: Have you tried changing the simulation space of the effect?